# jQuery libraries are conflicting

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap input range slider and it was working fine but when I am adding another jQuery library it stopped my jQuery slide can anyone help me out to resolve this issue?

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>//When I remove this library it is then working fine 
<script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/main.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slick.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#ex2").slider({});

        $('#ex20a').on('click', function(e) {
            $('#ex20a')
                .parent()
                .find(' >.well')
                .toggle()
                .find('input')
                .slider('relayout');
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem with conflicting name of the method.
Visit https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider#what-if-there-is-already-a-slider-plugin-bound-to-the-jquery-namespace